getAssociatedTokenAddressSync returns different token account address than the one in solscan
I am trying to get token accounts from mint and owner address.
Mint : 7HR9uH1QgDS53GfzoNgG9jieKVY1FARN1oYDQyZ63X4y  
Owner: GpMZbSM2GgvTKHJirzeGfMFoaZ8UR2X7F4v8vHTvxFbL -> Raydium LP Token
Token Program : TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID

With following code
getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, owner, true, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);

I am getting : gf8LBrffvbUh3zbnw4dGJ9nCuMAFJZhrG2aYrg2e6NJ
Whereas per solscan, it should be 2SwqDsKAMjLKYkUhwJGmSQ5aC3HShVJt2ZWH4i4tnRi4
https://solscan.io/account/2SwqDsKAMjLKYkUhwJGmSQ5aC3HShVJt2ZWH4i4tnRi4
Any idea ?

This address is not the associated token account. If you see the initialization transaction at https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4AA66xmswj3hkvW4fEvjFMdpBCFTckdq1sQgvn8tC2aRo4TD61kX3pufyLowHVHwVuqWiWb5w8Xkf8rNYBccDRyC, you'll see that the account is not created with the associated token account program in #4.12. It's likely some other program-derived address.
gf8LBrffvbUh3zbnw4dGJ9nCuMAFJZhrG2aYrg2e6NJ is the correct ATA.

The reason this doesn't work is because this is not an ATA. Instead, it's a Raydium vault PDA. You can see the seeds used to derive it here:
// The provided mint
const mint = new PublicKey('7HR9uH1QgDS53GfzoNgG9jieKVY1FARN1oYDQyZ63X4y');
// The state account for the provided market (https://solscan.io/account/5M1cRSDQT4aYZTgcCfoZc3At1A4cod861A2jcPes46jY)
const poolState = new PublicKey('5M1cRSDQT4aYZTgcCfoZc3At1A4cod861A2jcPes46jY');
// The Raydium CLMM program address
const prog = new PublicKey('CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C');
// From https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cp-swap/blob/59cfb316901c64cc4c40df68f88c6a31f078228a/programs/cp-swap/src/states/pool.rs#L7
const seed = 'pool_vault';

// From the Raydium source code linked above
const poolAccount = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from(seed), poolState.toBytes(), mint.toBytes()],
    prog,
)[0];

// Logs 2SwqDsKAMjLKYkUhwJGmSQ5aC3HShVJt2ZWH4i4tnRi4
console.log(poolAccount.toBase58());


